# Partially mock a method in unittest `setUp`

Tags: python, mocking, magicmock

I am trying to understand the mock/patch framework, but have a problem. Here are my simplified codes:

```
file_a.py
class A:
  def f(self): 
    b = B()
    b.g()
    b.h()

file_b.py
class B:
  def g(self):
    return network_requests(...)

  def h(self):
    return "This is should not be mocked."

file_test.py
class SomeTests:
  def setUp(self):
    with patch('file_b.B', autospec=True) as mock:
      mock.g.return_value = "Mocked value"
      mock.side_effect = lambda : B()
    self.a = A()

  def test(self):
    self.a.f()
```

Essentially I want to mock only `B.g` inside the test, but not `B.h`. I got some idea from https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking, but `B.g` is still not mocked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you linked the key problem is

> Unfortunately `datetime.date` is written in C

That is why you need to mock the module and wrap what you don't want to mock (You cannot patch C methods directly).

Is all other cases (patch python objects) you can use just :

```
with patch('file_b.B.g', autospec=True) as mock_g:
  mock_g.return_value = "Mocked value"
```

Anyway take care that your patch will be active just in the `with` context, out of it you will find the original reference. To have a better control of the context it you can use also decorators, `start()` and `stop()`.

I strongly encourage you read carefully [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) and [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).